# Python list within list

Tags: python

So i'm still pretty new to python, and I can't find a solution to this anywhere.

I need to recall a variable from list within a list:

```
data_sets = [
    ['O', ['1', 'place1', 'method1']],
    ['X', ['1', 'place2', 'method1']],
```

I need to be able to extract each one in context of the others: Item 1 goes in place 1, in this method vs item 1 goes in place 2 in this method, not just the whole line, or a 'contains'

```
print(data_sets[1])
```

Just prints the whole line - I need to call each word specifically for when it starts to have multiples in one...

```
['O', ['1', 'place4', 'method2'],
      ['2', 'place3', 'method2']],
```

The obvious data_sets[1,[2]] doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: What about `data_sets[1][2]`?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking. What exactly is the output you desire?

Comment: Verbose approach: `a = data_sets[1]; print(a[2])`…

Comment: It might be better to use a dictionary here for storing you data. It would still be of the syntax {'0': ['1', 'place1', 'method1']} but you will be able to reference your variable as data_sets["0"][2] ( or data_sets["key"][value_index] )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax `data_sets[1, [2]]` is slightly off, the correct way is

```
data_sets[1][2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data_sets[1]
```

this will return

```
['O', ['1', 'place1', 'method1']]
```

now think of this as another list that `data_sets[1]` has returned, now you can apply another index based unwrapping. like `data_set[1][0]` will return `0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
def accessor(lst):
for i in range(0, len(lst)):
    if type(lst[i])==int or type(lst[i])==float or type(lst[i])==str:
        print(lst[i])
    else:
        accessor(lst[i])
lst=[4, (2,3,[2,3,4],6), 7,5, 4.5, [6,2,4,['lk',4,5,(75,'ll')]], 'aditya', 7] #list contains a combination of int, float, str, list and tuple
accessor(lst)
```

As you can see that the given list contains combination of elements of various types along with multiple nested lists/tuples. It will also work with tuples

Hope this helps.